# How to get DIV sub-elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, adsense

HTML Code

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="unfilled">
```

I have checked : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp and tried but it not help.

I want to take this element `data-ad-status="unfilled"` from HTML using javascript. So, i can use it in if else statement.

Like

```
if (data-ad-status="unfilled") {
some fuctions; 
}
```

Comment: use `document.querySelector();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: your need querySelectorAll with a loop if you have multiple ads

Comment: Note that there also is [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) which - by limiting search to a DOM subtree - might allow for more concise selectors and improve performance.

Comment: `if ($(".adsbygoogle").data("ad-status") === "unfilled") { ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m not working. i tried your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As you told me that data is coming from `async` way I have added `setTimeOut()` function to wait for around 2 seconds here.
- I do not have access to how data is coming so this time for `2s` is hard coded. change it's value and try to run it. and I am sure it will solve your problem.
- But use `asyn-await` function and make `selectAd()` wait till you data get loaded.

```js
const selecteAd = () => {
  const myDiv = document.querySelector("[data-ad-status='unfilled']");
  const selectAllWithAttributeAdStatus = document.querySelectorAll("[data-ad-status]");
  /*This(selectAllWithAttributeAdStatus) one is just for showing how to select elements with data-ad-status attribute */
  //let adStatus = myDiv.getAttribute("data-ad-status");
  selectAllWithAttributeAdStatus.forEach(ad => {
    if ((ad.getAttribute("data-ad-status")) === "unfilled") {
      ad.style.background = "red";
      ad.style.height = "100px";
      ad.style.width = "100px";
      ad.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      ad.style.background = "green";
      ad.style.height = "100px";
      ad.style.width = "100px";
      ad.style.display = "inline-block";
    };
  })
}
const myTimeout = setTimeout(selecteAd, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="unfilled"></div>
<div class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="somethingelse"></div>
```

Comment: This code working fine but after 2 seconds. it also removing whole web page HTML and making the webpage blank. Link : https://thebibleinformation.com/a-ad.php

Comment: Hey I have run it's working fine you now you just need to implement it with proper ```asyn-await``` function.

Comment: I have visited your website ti's showing red blocks, you have to make ```asyn-await``` function which waits till ads loaded and them work I have just imitating this as after 2 second.

Comment: Yes, like i said it working fine. It showing red block. But have you noticed it removed other content of the site. including ad code, text, other images, lines everything.

Comment: Check the `view source` of the page. it have lot of content. Your code working fine but instead removing whole website content and making a HTML blank in `inspect element`

Comment: The script replace whole HTML with `<div style="background:red; height:10px; width:10px"></div>` defined inside the if else statement.

Comment: I also noticed. There is only two ads but 3 red bar showing. can you check it?

Comment: what do you want to do? yo just want to replace those unfilled dive with red background?

Comment: No. i just want a indicator. if ads shown it will display green bar and if ads not showing it will display red bar at any part of website. (Eg, maybe at top left small indicator which says ad showing or not showing).

I do not want to make changes to other content of the page.

Comment: I have change answer, try it now as it is

Comment: @SunilKumar I found this ad event listener docs from google, and it seems to work for this case very good,  **demo example:** https://googleads.github.io/google-publisher-tag-samples/advanced/ad-event-listeners/demo.html, **how to use it (docs):** https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/ad-event-listeners

Answer (score 3):

```js
/*SELECTING BY CLASSANEMES*/
const withClassName = document.querySelectorAll(".adsbygoogle");
withClassName.forEach(ad => {
  if ((ad.getAttribute("data-ad-status")) === "unfilled") {
    console.log("unfilled ad element")
  } else {
    console.log("other ad element")
  };
})
```

```html
<div class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="unfilled"></div>
<div class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="somethingelse"></div>
```

-`document.querySelector("[data-ad-status='unfilled']` this one is electing particular one with `data-ad-status="unfillded"`

- `document.querySelectorAll("[data-ad-status]");` this one is selecting all with the `data-ad-status` attribute.

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector("[data-ad-status='unfilled']");

const selectAllWithAttributeAdStatus = document.querySelectorAll("[data-ad-status]");
/*This(selectAllWithAttributeAdStatus) one is just for showing how to select elements with data-ad-status attribute */
//let adStatus = myDiv.getAttribute("data-ad-status");
selectAllWithAttributeAdStatus.forEach(ad => {
  if ((ad.getAttribute("data-ad-status")) === "unfilled") {
    console.log("unfilled ad element")
  } else {
    console.log("other ad element")
  };
})
```

```html
<div class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="unfilled"></div>
<div class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done" data-ad-status="somethingelse"></div>
```

Comment: I have applied your code but no luck. here is my link : https://thebibleinformation.com/a-ad.php

Comment: ```const adStatusM = document.querySelector("[data-ad-status='unfilled']").getAttribute("data-ad-status");``` try this now with ```if(adStatusM == "unfilled")```.

Comment: @SunilKumar I have change my answer could you just apply it?

Comment: @SunilKumar is your data coming in async way?

Comment: Yes async way. it will take atleast 200ms to update filled or unfilled status.

Comment: I have placed your new code but still no luck. HTML code generated in client browser side. In coding it an adsense ad javascript code. you can check above link `inspect element` and `view source`

Comment: Hey sunil just create one async function put my code in it as current code going in async mode that's why we are not getting able to complete it.

Answer (score 3):

we can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select our element *(if there is only one)*

but in this case we need to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for selecting all the ads elements in html (`<ins>`)

also now we can loop your logic on every element with that status, using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> with `forEach` you can get 3 other information,
>
>  - the element itself (which you can do your logic with, or console.log it)
>
>  - the index of the element
>
>  - the array of all the elements
>
> ---
>
> with this order `(element, indexOfElement, ArrayOfAllElements)`

**this is a example:**

```js
let unfilledAds = document.querySelectorAll(`.adsbygoogle[data-ad-status="unfilled"]`);
let successAds = document.querySelectorAll(`.adsbygoogle[data-ad-status="success"]`);;

/* not success */
unfilledAds.forEach((adElement) => {
    /* your logic */
    console.log(`❌ this Ad is not filled`, adElement);
});

/* success */
successAds.forEach((adElement) => {
    console.log(`✅ this ad is visible to the user`, adElement);
});
```

```html
<!-- fail -->
    <ins data-ad-status="unfilled" class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"></ins>
    <ins data-ad-status="unfilled" class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"></ins>

    <!-- success -->
    <ins data-ad-status="success" class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"></ins>
    <ins data-ad-status="success" class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1714167228247329" data-ad-slot="8611448539" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"></ins>
```

---

> you can also generalize `[data-ad-status]` by selecting all the elements and then do a simple if, else (checking the result)

> you can also use this custom google event for the ads https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/ad-event-listeners without reinventing the wheels 
>  so it will work if the ads will be successful after some time. 
>  
>  just see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/ad-event-listeners).
>
>  here a example: https://googleads.github.io/google-publisher-tag-samples/advanced/ad-event-listeners/demo.html

Comment: I applied your code but not working. here is my link : https://thebibleinformation.com/a-ad.php . Maybe it take 1-2 seconds to update `unfilled` or `filled`?

Comment: @SunilKumar ok you can use the ad event listeners from google https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/ad-event-listeners they have literally what you need! here a demo example https://googleads.github.io/google-publisher-tag-samples/advanced/ad-event-listeners/demo.html