# Get and replace string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dom

My website have lot of links and i am trying to replace all `a href` target `_top` to `_blank`. How can i do this with javascript?

It will find all `_top` in my web page and replace with `_blank`

I am trying like this :

```js
// const string = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML
const string = document.querySelector("_top"); //getting string
var newstring = string.replace(/_top/, '_blank'); //trying to replace string in whole page
const myTimeout = setTimeout(selecteAd, 2000); //set timeout so webpage get loaded full
```

```html
<!-- example string -->
<a data-asoch-targets="imageClk" href="https://www.eample.com" target="_top" x-ns-8l6in-e="2"><canvas class="ns-8l6in-e-3 image" x-ns-8l6in-e="3" width="600" height="314"></canvas></a>
```

Updated :

Data is coming from Google adsense `async` code. (Got similar solution in other part of Stackoverflow but still i am unsuccessful in replacing [How to get DIV sub-elements using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803875/how-to-get-div-sub-elements-using-javascript) )

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll

```
$(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("a[target=_top]").forEach(function(elem) {
    this.target="_blank";
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to original answers who deleted the answer :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_top"]').forEach(el => el.target = '_blank');
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_top">foo</a><br />
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_top">bar</a>
```